# Console.ReadLine returns null when input consists of the single char U+2192 (ASCII: 1A)

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Rider 2022.1 EAP 7 targeting .NET 6.0.200.

The following characters are being tested:

- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2190
- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2191
- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2192
- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2193

But specifically entering U+2192 (codepoint 1A in ASCII) to `Console.In` leaves `Console.ReadLine()` returning `null`.

Using the following code:

```cs
var upArrow = ((char)0x18).ToString();
var downArrow = ((char)0x19).ToString();
var rightArrow = ((char)0x1A).ToString();
var leftArrow = ((char)0x1B).ToString();

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Input: ");
    string? input = Console.ReadLine();
    
    if (input == upArrow) Console.WriteLine("Up arrow");
    else if (input == downArrow) Console.WriteLine("Down arrow");
    else if (input == rightArrow) Console.WriteLine("Right arrow");
    else if (input == leftArrow) Console.WriteLine("Left arrow");
    else if (input is null) Console.WriteLine("Null");
}
```

The output is as follows, testing the different arrow characters:

```
Input: ↑
Up arrow
Input: ↓
Down arrow
Input: ←
Left arrow
Input: →
Null
```

I would, obviously, expect it to print "Right arrow", but instead it's null - and I have no idea why.

At first I thought this was due to character encoding issue, because Rider's integrated terminal uses [Codepage 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) - but this encoding (which is basically ASCII anyway) defines the right arrow at codepoint 1A. So it's not as if the character is not supported. I mean, the other arrows are anyway.

Comment: Okay, so upon further inspection, it appears this is not specifically a C# issue but perhaps a Windows issue? I've written the equivalent logic in C++ (here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/oliverbooth/e479529e5fe8bfbb58f370560c06e53b)) - and the same thing is happening.

Comment: Ctrl+Z is the end-of-file indicator for a Windows console.  For *nix terminals it is Ctrl+D.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh my god you're right. I can't believe I missed that! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans in the comment of my question explaining the issue!

0x1A maps to Ctrl+Z sequence which is an EOF indicator in Windows consoles. The right arrow just so happens to map to this same sequence by pure coincidence.